# Cannot convert the value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable"

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

In Azure Devops I'm trying to run a block of Azure Powershell inline script:

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName xxx-Name xxx -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY/_alias/xxx.ps1 -Parameter $env:xxx -Verbose
```

As you can see I am passing a parameter to the xxx.ps1 script. This is a small piece of the content of the xxx.ps1 script:

```
Param(
[string]$xxx
)

#create AD Group
$ADGroupName = "AD" + $xxx+ "_AD"
.....
```

When I run this code I get the following error in the logs:

> [error]Cannot bind parameter 'Parameter'. Cannot convert the "valueofthevariable" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".

How can I correctly pass the value as parameter?
Thanks!

Comment: by reading this you should be able to create a proper hashtable and use it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6 also see some uses in this issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8458

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more searching online I found my mistake:

In the Powershell command Invoke-AzVMRunCommand I used a String as input type for Parameter, this has to be a hashtable.
I changed that command to the following:

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName xxx-Name xxx -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY/_alias/xxx.ps1 -Parameter @{xxx = $env:xxx} -Verbose
```