# Powershell - Azure AD : User creation - PasswordProfile error message

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am doing some tests to manage Azure AD users and groups with Powershell.
Unfortunately, i have an issue when i try to create an user. Here my code :

#Specifies the user's password profile.
*$PasswordProfile=New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
$PasswordProfile.Password = "xxxx"*

#Create a AzureAD user account
*PS C:\Windows\system32> New-AzureADUser `-DisplayName "Power SHELL"`
-GivenName "Power" `-SurName "SHELL"`*
*-UserPrincipalName power.shell@xxxx.xx `-UsageLocation FR`
-MailNickName Power Shell `-PasswordProfile $PasswordProfile`
-AccountEnabled $true*

When I validate the PasswordProfile, I have this error message :

*New-AzureADUser: Failed to bind parameter 'PasswordProfile'. Cannot convert value '$PasswordProfile' of type 'System.String to type “Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile”.*

I look in a lot of forum but i can't find any solution to make it works.

Thanks for your help.

Geoffrey

Answer (score 0):

***I could create the user successfully with the commands you have provided and as per [microsoftDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/new-user-sample?view=azureadps-2.0):***

[image]

***Result:***
[image]

***I could reproduce the issue with error:***

```
 Cannot bind parameter 'PasswordProfile'. 
" value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile".
```

when i actually placed quotes around $PasswordProfile like below

```
New-AzureADUser -DisplayName "xxx" -GivenName "xx" -SurName "xx" -UserPrincipalName xxxx.onmicrosoft.com -UsageLocation US -MailNickName navy -PasswordProfile "$PasswordProfile" -AccountEnabled $true
```

[image]

So please try by placing  ***$PasswordProfile in quotes*** in your case to resolve the issue.

***`-PasswordProfile "$PasswordProfile"`***

similar case here : [Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type .. | techcommunity.microsoft.com](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-powershell/cannot-convert-system-object-to-the-type-microsoft/m-p/435723)

Please make sure password is valid and check if string as input type for Parameter somehting like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55343464/cannot-convert-the-value-of-type-system-string-to-type-system-collections-has)

or

Try this way:

```
    $PasswordProfile = New-Object -TypeName     
      Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
   
    $PasswordProfile.Password = "Ixxxxxxxk"
   
    $params = @{
    AccountEnabled = $true
    DisplayName = "xxxn"
    PasswordProfile = $PasswordProfile
    UserPrincipalName = "xxx@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
    MailNickName = "xxxxx"
    }
   
    New-AzureADUser @params
```

References:
[set-azureaduserlicense-cannot-bind-parameter-assignedlicenses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66245678/set-azureaduserlicense-cannot-bind-parameter-assignedlicenses)